# Why use different Queue when creating FixedThreadPool and CachedThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading

Executors#newFixedThreadPool:

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

Executors#newCachedThreadPool:

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                  60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                  new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

Why the two threadPool use different Queue?
I have looked up java doc about [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) and [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html),but I still don't know why they are used here,Is performance considering or others?

Comment: Is it a duplicate ? It does not ask the same question. The response can have something in common, but it is a different question.

Comment: Reason from related SE question:SynchronousQueue is a very special kind of queue - it implements a rendezvous approach (producer waits until consumer is ready, consumer waits until producer is ready) behind the interface of Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation of the class ThreadPoolExecutor:

> - Queuing
> - - Any {@link BlockingQueue} may be used to transfer and hold
>   - submitted tasks.  The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:  *  *
>
>       *  *
>     - If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor  * always prefers adding a new thread  * rather than
>         queuing.
>       *  *
>     - If corePoolSize or more threads are running,
>         the Executor  * always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a
>         new  * thread.
>       *  *
>     - If a request cannot be queued, a new
>         thread is created unless  * this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in
>         which case, the task will be  * rejected.
>       *  *
>
>     *  * There
>       are three general strategies for queuing:  *   *  *
>
>     *Direct handoffs.* A good default choice for a work  * queue is a
>       **{@link SynchronousQueue} that hands off tasks to threads**  * without
>       otherwise holding them. Here, an attempt to queue a task  * will fail
>       if no threads are immediately available to run it, so a  * new thread
>       will be constructed. This policy avoids lockups when  * handling sets
>       of requests that might have internal dependencies.  * Direct handoffs
>       generally require unbounded maximumPoolSizes to  * avoid rejection of
>       new submitted tasks. This in turn admits the  * possibility of
>       unbounded thread growth when commands continue to  * arrive on average
>       faster than they can be processed.
>
>     *  *
>
>     *Unbounded
>       queues.* **Using an unbounded queue (for  * example a {@link
>       LinkedBlockingQueue}** without a predefined  * capacity) will cause new
>       tasks to wait in the queue when all  * corePoolSize threads are busy.
>       Thus, no more than corePoolSize  * threads will ever be created. (And
>       the value of the maximumPoolSize  * therefore doesn't have any
>       effect.)  This may be appropriate when  * each task is completely
>       independent of others, so tasks cannot  * affect each others
>       execution; for example, in a web page server.  * While this style of
>       queuing can be useful in smoothing out  * transient bursts of
>       requests, it admits the possibility of  * unbounded work queue growth
>       when commands continue to arrive on  * average faster than they can be
>       processed.
>
>     *  *
>
>     *Bounded queues.* A bounded queue
>       (for example, an  * {@link ArrayBlockingQueue}) helps prevent resource
>       exhaustion when  * used with finite maximumPoolSizes, but can be more
>       difficult to  * tune and control.  Queue sizes and maximum pool sizes
>       may be traded  * off for each other: Using large queues and small
>       pools minimizes  * CPU usage, OS resources, and context-switching
>       overhead, but can  * lead to artificially low throughput.  If tasks
>       frequently block (for  * example if they are I/O bound), a system may
>       be able to schedule  * time for more threads than you otherwise allow.
>       Use of small queues  * generally requires larger pool sizes, which
>       keeps CPUs busier but  * may encounter unacceptable scheduling
>       overhead, which also  * decreases throughput.

In practice the first type of queue immediately send to the available threads a new Runnable, the second type holds it if all the threads are busy.

Comment: Both APIS return unbounded queues.

Comment: @ravindra Modified my answer